# matlab removing redundant objects from a list of objects (arrays)

Tags: matlab, list, unique, scilab

In matlab or scilab, how can someone remove redundant entries in a list of array objects ? and perhaps save it as a matrix ?

example:

```
p = list();
p(1) = ['a' 'b' 'c'];
p(2) = ['a' 'b' 'c'];
p(3) = ['b' 'a' 'c']
```

For instance, starting from the list noted above, I want to get to a list q as

```
q(1) = ['a' 'b' 'c'];
q(2) = ['b' 'a' 'c'];
```

The unique function only works on arrays but not on list of arrays. I can do this manually by going through all the matrices, but it is not very efficient.

Comment: What do you mean by "redundant entries" ? Are you looking for the `unique` function? Perhaps you can show "I consider _this_ to be a redundant entry" - we can't read your mind... Usually a "if I start with this, I want to end up with that" way of formulating (and "here is what I tried") is a good way to get useful answers.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. I see your point, I am gonna update my question.

Comment: Much clearer now! I will give it some thought - it is a bit different from how I normally use Matlab... Have you tried playing with `ismember`?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I imagine ismember runs on sets. I guess I can try to play with it in a loop, but it will still be inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a built-in function designed for this task and I suspect there isn't one. I see four options:

1. write your own function that operates on a list of arrays. This is likely to be as inefficient as you suspect, though you might be able to do something with `unique`. Unfortunately, when you try to do e.g. `p(:)(2)`, as if to extract the second element of each list entry, you get `Not implemented in scilab...`
2. convert the list of arrays to a matrix. I've had to do this using for loops and it takes geological time (if anyone knows a better way I'd love to hear it) but once the data are in matrix form you can slice them, which could make it easier to compare rows elementwise:

   `q = ['a' 'b' 'c'; 'd' 'e' 'f']`

   then you can do stuff like

   q(:,2)
3. save the data out and process it in ruby or python instead (or compile some ruby or python code and run it from within scilab) using their string handling features. Scilab's strengths are, like Matlab, in the speed of its vectorised operations. If you can't use the vectorised functions on a type of data structure then you have to ask whether it's worth using that tool for that job (or that datatype - see No. 2)
4. Depending on the nature of your cell elements you might be able to encode them numerically and compare row sums: if your elements really are single characters then maybe each one could be converted to a numeric value, multiplied by a factor appropriate to its column position and then the row summed. Comparing the sums of each row would then give you a quicker way of identifying duplicates. Of course if your data are really '21a acacia avenue' then your encoding scheme would become more like a hash but it might still be workable.

Comment: Yup. It seems like there is no built in function for doing this. I was thinking of a function that translates a list of arrays to a 2d matrix. If there is such function, then I can use `unique' function on its rows...